# On unchecking a checkbox trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="filter" name="Bedroom">
    <a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> Bedroom </a>           
</li>

<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="7" class="filter" name="Living Room">
    <a id="7" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> Living Room </a>           
</li>

<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="6" class="filter" name="Corridor">
    <a id="6" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> Corridor </a>          
</li>
</ul>
```

java script

```
<script>

    var id='';
    jQuery('.filter').click(function(){          

    jQuery('.filter').each(function(){      
        if(jQuery(this).attr('checked'))
        {
            id+=jQuery(this).val()+',';
        }               
    });
       alert(id);

        jQuery.get('<?php echo $this->getUrl('some url') ?>',{cat:id},function(data){   
      jQuery('#id').html(data);
        });
    });         
    </script>
```

Suppose I checked a checkbox I am getting the id of that check box.

```
id+=jQuery(this).val()+',';
```

How to remove the the id of element on unchecking a checkbox from id variable ?

I am trying to make an ajax call,When I click on  the check boxes then I should get 
a url containing the ids of the checkboxes example .../?cat=7%2C7%2C6%2C

and on unchecking the check boxes those check boxes ids should not be present

Comment: The click event gets called for both check and uncheck.  Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added an answer based on your updated question...

Comment: Thank you all the guys who posted the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be creating duplicate ids in the list, an easy solution is to recreate the id string every time like

```
var id;
var $checks = jQuery('.filter').change(function () {
    id= $checks.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YtQa9/)

Comment: Nice touch on storing the original selection in `$checks`. )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, below is the javascript that you are looking for:

```
var id='';
$('.filter').click(function(){          
    id='';
    $('.filter').each(function(){      
        if(this.checked)
        {
            id+=$(this).val()+',';
        }               
    });
    alert(id);
});
```

I think the key is to re-initialize the id variable to blank, so you do not keep adding values to it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3Zp7/) for working example

Comment: Thanks , I wanted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a String, but use an array:

```
var ids = new Array();
```

For the check don't use the click event, but the change event:

```
$(".filter").change(function() {


   if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      // Add the id to the list
      ids.push($(this).attr("id")); // Note the attribute, not the val()!
   } else {

      var index = -1;
      $.each(ids, function(idx, value) {
          if (value == $(this).attr("id")) index = idx;

      });

      ids.splice(idx, 1); //Remove the id
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider another approach.

```
var ids = [];
jQuery('.filter').change(function(){          
    ids = []; // Reinitialize array
    jQuery('.filter:checked').each(function(){
        ids.push(this.value);
    });
    alert(ids.join(',')); // Stringifies your array, using a comma as a separator.
});   

// You have access to ID's in outer scope as well!
```

Some may consider it a "performance hit" by reinitializing every time,
but seeing as you only have very few checkboxes, I see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question text was:

> How to remove the id of element on unchecking a checkbox?

Answer:

```
jQuery('.mySelector').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('id');
}
```

You may test this snippet on any website that loads jQuery, i.e. jquery.com - open in browser, hit `F12` and paste this into the console (and watch it destroy the whole CSS ;) ):

```
$('div').each(function() { $(this).removeAttr('id'); }
```

---

Update:
From reading your updated question, i believe what you are asking for is pretty much covered by the answers above.

**My two cents**: `id` was (and still is) amiguous in your question context, better names for the variable would be `ids`, `csvIdString`, `concatenatedCheckboxIds`, or whatever describes the variable best in its context (following [Clean Code Philosophy](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/))