# How to remove value when a checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on a search box which has three different fields which will be filled with ajax according to user's selection.

This is my html:

```
<div id="states">
    <input type="checkbox" name="states[]" value="01">
    <label for="states">State 01</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="states[]" value="02">
    <label for="states">State 02</label>
    ...etc...
</div>

<div id="prov">
    <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="01">
    <label for="states">Prov 01</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="02">
    <label for="states">Prov 02</label>
    ...etc...
</div>

<div id="cities">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="01">
    <label for="states">City 01</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="02">
    <label for="states">City 02</label>
    ...etc...
</div>
```

When you select the first set of checkboxes, the second one gets filled with all the provs acording to the states. So if State 1 has three provs, those provs show. If I also check State 2, then the provs for State 2 will append to the ones already showing from State 1.

Then the same thing for cities, it will show the respective cities to the checked provs.

I look at this question: [On unchecking a checkbox trigger an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843677/on-unchecking-a-checkbox-trigger-an-event) And did the following:

```
function(){
    var stateIds;
    var locUrl = $('#url');
    var $checks = jQuery('.dptoCheckbox').change(function () {
        stateIds= $checks.filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(',');
        console.log(stateIds);

        $.ajax({
            url: locUrl,
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: "state_ids="+stateIds,
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                $('#prov').html(data);          
            }
        });
    });
```

Then in my controller I retrieve the provs from DB by using the States ID.

So far it is working great, the only problem is, since I'm updating the ajax call everytime I check/uncheck a field. Consider this list:

- State 1

  - Prov A
  - Prov B
- State 2

  - Prov C
  - Prov D

If I check State 1 and State 2, then check Prov A and Prov C. Then I decide I no longer want State 2. If I uncheck State 2, a new ajax call is made and the provs list updates. Which causes first, Prov C to dissappear (this is correct behaviour) but also all the values checked from State 1 (Prov A) reset.

I was wondering if there is a way to update the provs lists (and later on the cities list) and only remove the provs from the uncheck State. Leaving all the other provs from other checked States as they were.

Thank you for reading this far, I hope I made my question clear, I wasn't sure how to explain it without writing my entire code (I tried to minimize it as much as possible).

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote? I've looked everywhere for a question like this and haven't found one. If it is a duplicate, please kindly show me the question. If it is something else please explain.

Comment: Load the provs as json data and add/remove the prov with javascript instead of relying on PHP to create the new html.

Comment: you mean instead of making a DB call with PHP to retrieve the data, I should store it on a json? And how can I add/remove provs using json and javascript?

Comment: No, you can make a DB call with PHP to retrieve the data on load, but then store the data as json in javascript.

Comment: Wouldnt that load the entire list of provs and hide them in the html? The thing is number of provs is huge. I got 24 States, each of which have 20+ provs. And then each prov has 15+ cities. Would that slow down the load time of site?

Comment: Not really. You have two options. Either you can load them directly on first load (then when the page gets called, do db call and json_encode() the lists `var list_a = JSON.parse('".$json_list_a."')`. Or you can load the data via AJAX.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm afraid I don't follow. How could I load the data via AJAX? Am I not doing that already?

Comment: You're loading the HTML code with the processed data with AJAX, not the plain data. That's why your checkboxes gets resetted.

Comment: Finally I'm done... Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/zxtpcm8g/). Maybe it's an obvious decision, but it is better than original one and than full list loading.

Comment: @Regent I just tried it and it worked. Thank you so much!!! I don't quite understand how this `$('#prov .js-states' + $(this).val()).remove();` removes only the provs from the unchecked state. edit: nevermind just figured it out!! it's by adding a class + state value.

Comment: @Ant100 you're welcome. For example, for `<input value="01">` it results in `$('#prov .js-states01)`. Inside `#prov` there are elements with class `js-states01` (we added this class for received `data` elements (in ajax success function) during `<input value="01">` checking). So during checking we add elements with related class, during unchecking - remove elements with related class. You can see in fiddle that all elements inside `#prov` have class based on their states parent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess, but I haven't tested it completely, and I'm not an expert javascript programmer either.  Let me know if there are any errors.  EDIT: here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/z590wdLo/3/

NOTE: This answer has been proven wrong.  It's missing code to remove provinces that shouldn't be there.  I'm not deleting it because it could be slightly modified to be useful.

First of all you're HTML is slightly messed up.  One of the main goals of a label element is so that when the user clicks the label, it checks the box for them.  The way your markup is written doesn't allow this.  You need to change this:

```
<div id="prov">
    <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="01">
    <label for="states">Province 01</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="02">
    <label for="states">Province 02</label>
    ...etc...
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="prov">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="01"/>
        Province 01
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="02"/>
        Province 02
    </label>
    ...etc...
</div>
```

I changed this on the `#states` div but you should change it on everything.  Notice that I took away the `for="states"` attribute and also put the `<input type="checkbox"...` element inside the `<label>` element.

You also should have your server return results in JSON and change the data type of your request to match. You can do this in PHP with the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.  I'm not sure your JSON object will look like exactly, so you'll have to modify the code accordingly.  I'm going to assume you have a numerical array of associative arrays which will each have items in them, `provName` and `provID`.

I'm also assuming that the `value="01"` in `<input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="01">` is the `provID` and that `Prov 01` in `<label for="states">Prov 01</label>` is the `provName`.

Also change this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#prov').html(data);          
}
```

To this:

```
success: function(data) {

    var province = [];
    var elements;

    //get the next element from the array and only continue if
    //there actually was something left to get
    while((province = data.pop) !== undefined) {

        //do not append the element if there already exists an element
        //is a descendent of div#prov,
        //is of the type input,
        //and has a value that matches the provinceID
        if($("div#prov input[value|='" + province.provID + "']") !== $()) {

            $('#prov').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="' + province.provID + '"/>' + province.provName + '</label>');

        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that @Regent answered the question in the comments before I was able to come up with my answer.

Comment: Sending JSON instead of HTML is indeed more proper way to pass data. But you didn't say anything about deleting no more necessary (after unchecking) elements. Also it's better to send data for newly checked element rather than send data for all checked elements, don't you agree with this?

Comment: @Regent you're right.  Would you like to edit that yourself?  I have a deadline to meet so I can't do it within the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to do this:

1) Control all the checked checkboxes in server side, and serve the checked content on every AJAX call

2) Deleting the child checkboxes without AJAX, you should add on every province a class with the state dependency, and on every city a class with the province dependency. I think this is the better way.

I will explain the second one with an example:

When the user check the state 01, a province 12 is added by AJAX call:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="provs[]" value="12" class="province_state_01">
```

When the user check the province 12, the city 23 is added:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="23" class="city_province_12">
```

Now, if the user uncheck the province 01, we should delete the child cities, without AJAX call:

```
jQuery('#prov input').change(function () {
    if (!jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        province_unchecked = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('input.city_province_' + province_unchecked ).remove();
    } else {
        //Here you should add your AJAX call to add the cities
    }
});
```

Now, let's do the same for the states, we should iterate for cities:

```
jQuery('#states input').change(function () {
    if (!jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        state_unchecked = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('input.province_state_' + state_unchecked).each(function() {
            province_child = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery('input.city_province_' + province_child ).remove();
            jQuery(this).remove();
        });
    } else {
        //Here you should add your AJAX call to add the provinces
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably you should mention in answer that you are adding classes to `input`s on Ajax request's success. And one important thing: if you only add class for `input`s and only delete `input`s, you will end up with a lot of forsaken  `label`s in page :)

Comment: @Regent: You're right: the label + input should be wrapped with some tag, like <p> or <span>, and it must have the class with parent info.